# Duplicate delete query in binary log of MySQL Master

Tags: mysql, replication

We are facing a strange problem, while replicating data from master to slave. Same data is being deleted twice in log (however, only one row is deleted and one time), due to which we are getting error while replicating:

```
# at 28651234
#150423 12:21:03 server id 5170  end_log_pos 28651303 CRC32 0x0b496431  Delete_rows: table id 73 flags: STMT_END_F
### DELETE FROM `oauth`.`AccessToken_scopes`
### WHERE
###   @1=1040103520
###   @2='wallet'
### DELETE FROM `oauth`.`AccessToken_scopes`
### WHERE
###   @1=1040103520
###   @2='wallet'
```

To avoid this,we currently have added below parameter in `my.cnf` file:

```
slave-skip-errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slave-skip-errors` can hide even serious errors; don't do it.

Turn on the "general log" briefly.  This should capture a little more info about where the duplicate `DELETE` is coming from.  One of two things will happen:

- There will be two `DELETEs` in the general log, too.  This will point at the application for issuing the delete twice.
- There will be one in the general log but two in the binlog.  In this case, move on to the next step.

Do you have the binlog for replication?  If so, turn on the general log on a Slave to see if the duplicate stuff in the binlog really represents two `DELETEs`, not just some kind of stuttering in `mysqlbinlog`.

In any case file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com; the different paths give you different ways to complain.

Comment: I see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64139,and reported same as new also.